# How to rearrange a pool of posts joined using two queries?

Tags: query, sort, date

I need to select posts for two different months (current, past). As far as i know, it is not possible to pass `m` date parameter as an array of integer instead of an integer, so I am performing two different queries and getting all posts returned into the same array.

The question is, how do i reorder the result pool of posts? Just pushing the second pool into the array returned by the first query isn't enough, as the `orderby` argument finds a *discontinuity* in the joint of the two arrays.

I tried using `usort` but I get an error saying that `You can't use WP_Post object as an array`.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: To clarify, you want posts that were posted in this month, and last month?

Comment: Yes, both months, say, today it is a date interval of 31 days, by the end of October the interval will span to almost 60 days.

Comment: I found solutions for "get last 30 days posts" but all seem to apply a filter where, modifying query string. I'm querying using an array, and I found that the date parameter specifying month was a better solution. Also, the `date_query` implemented for WP 3.7 doesnt fit for this project, that is using latest stable release to date (3.6.1)

Comment: Nothing wrong with modifying the query string... (and 3.7 hopefully won't be long :))

Comment: but @StephenHarris, I'm preparing my query for `get_posts` setting query parameters as an associative array. How do I apply the `WHERE` filter in this case?

Comment: I think i found a pointer... i have to prevent get_posts from suppress the filter http://www.viper007bond.com/2010/02/02/wordpress-using-filters-with-get_posts/

Comment: indeed `suppress_filters=>false` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would approach it:

#### Code

```
function my_pseudo_date_query( $where, $query ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $dq = $query->get('my_date_query');

    if( $dq && !empty( $dq['after'] ) ){

        $where .=  $wpdb->prepare( 
                      " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date >= %s"
                      $dq['after']
                   );
    }

    if( $dq && !empty( $dq['before'] ) ){

        $where .=  $wpdb->prepare( 
                     " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date <= %s",
                      $dq['before']
                   );
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'post_where', 'my_pseudo_date_query', 10, 2 );
```

#### Example usage:

```
$now = new DateTime( 'now' );
$first_of_last_month = new DateTime( 'first day of last month' );
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
 'my_date_query' => array(
      'before' => $now->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
      'after' => $first_of_last_month->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
  );
 ) );
```

The *before* argument is redundant in this example.

#### Remarks

1. This hasn't been tested, it's code 'in principle'.
2. I've been quite lazy here and the `before` and `after` keys of the `my_date_query` attribute are quite strict. They *must* be in the `Y-m-d H:i:s` (php) format. But it's enough for this answer.
3. As noted in the comments [**WordPress 3.7**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18694) will provide `date_query` as an argument. The above code is 'forward compatible' in the sense that once you've upgraded to 3.7, you can remove the `my_` prefix from the example.
4. The example assumes **PHP5.3+**. Though its fairly simple to workaround this limitation.
5. If using with `get_posts()` don't forget to set `suppress_filters` to **false**.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, as you point out, the issue with the filter was that get_posts defaults suppress_filters to **true** :) Thanks for the explanation, looking forward to have 3.7 on production sites ;)